# Curve fitting with scipy in python to find correction parameters (can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64')

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit the function h = a0*L(1-a1*L**(-w1) to my graph and find the parameters a0, a1, and w1. I cant figure out why it's not working. I keep getting the error: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
L = [8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256]
Average_height = [12.973731636721096,26.52865044449718,53.85333875018466,108.90761725203599,219.30647736483996,428.833120246036]

def correction(L, a0, a1, w1):
    return a0*L*(1-a1*L**(-w1))
popt, pcov = curve_fit(correction, L, Average_height, bounds =([0,0,-10], [10,10,10]))
a0, a1, w1 = popt
print((a0, a1, w1)) 
plt.plot(L, correction(L, *popt), 'r-')
plt.show()
```

Comment: For a start turn all your lists into numpy arrays.  `[1,2,3]*3` means repeat the list 3 times.

Comment: @hpaulj Well, in some cases it might be desired to not use `numpy`. In such a case you could add lines as `if isinstance( L, (list, tuple) ):` and then `return ( [correction( elem, a0, a1, w1 ) for elem in L ]`

Answer (score 0):

As hpaulj already mentioned, you should use numpy arrays. There was also a stray comma that must have been a typo because otherwise, you would have had different numbers of x- and y-values. Finally, you cannot generally use the Python power function `**` with numpy arrays - there is the dedicated numpy function [np.power](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.power.html) for this. Changing the code accordingly leads to this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

L = np.asarray([8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256])
Average_height = np.asarray([12.973731636721096,26.52865044449718,53.85333875018466,108.90761725203599,219.30647736483996,428.833120246036])

def correction(L, a0, a1, w1):
    return a0*L*(1-a1* np.power(L, -w1))
popt, pcov = curve_fit(correction, L, Average_height, bounds =([0,0,-10], [10,10,10]))
print(*popt) 
#1.6836463115082618 9.999999999965157 2.717334174156468
plt.scatter(L, Average_height, label="Data")
plt.plot(L, correction(L, *popt), 'r-', label="fit")
plt.show()
```

Output
[image]